# Moving drawn shape to new Y with steps

Tags: javascript, canvas, html5-canvas, 2d-games

I'm Working on my LD entry and I'm a little stuck, so time is of the essence.

I'm working in vanilla JS and have a tennis/pong style set up. there are two buttons, one at the top half and one at the bottom half of the canvas.

I have it working so that when clicked they move the 'ball' - or + on the Y axis. **But I want it so that when clicked the 'ball' begins move to the other side, and it begins moving to the other side. can just be 0 and canvas.height respectively,** 
 but i don't know how to go about coding this.

One other feature is that I'd like is that you can only click a side if the 'ball' is colliding.

CodePen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/objWKN

```
var canvas, ctx, mouseX, mouseY, btn1, btn2, ball, ballX, ballY, ballSize, Score;

window.onload = function main() {

canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
canvas.width = width = 320;
canvas.height = height = 560;
mouseX = 0;
mouseY = 0;
btn1 = new Button(0, width, 0, height/2);
btn2 = new Button(0, width, height/2, height);
moveX = width/2;
moveY = height/2;
ballSize = 20;
ballX = moveX;
ballY = moveY;

document.body.appendChild(canvas);

init();
}


function init() {
document.addEventListener('click', mouseClicked, false);

update();
}


function update() {


ctx.clearRect(0, 0, 300, 300);

ctx.beginPath();
ctx.fillStyle="red";
ctx.rect(0, height/2, width, height/2);
ctx.fill();
ctx.closePath();

ctx.beginPath();
ctx.fillStyle = "black";
ctx.arc( ballX, ballY , ballSize/2, 0, Math.PI * 2, true);
ctx.fill();
ctx.closePath();  
}



// button object
// checks if within bounds of 'button'
function Button(xL, xR, yT, yB) {
this.xLeft = xL;
this.xRight = xR;
this.yTop = yT;
this.yBottom = yB;
}

Button.prototype.checkClicked = function() {
if ( this.xLeft <= mouseX && mouseX <= this.xRight && this.yTop <= mouseY && mouseY <= this.yBottom) return true;
};



// event functions
// get position of mouse if its clicked on the canvas
function mouseClicked(e) {

mouseX = e.pageX - canvas.offsetLeft;
mouseY = e.pageY - canvas.offsetTop;

//btn1 clicked = move up
for (i = ballY; i > height; i++); {
    if (btn1.checkClicked()) { 
           ballY = ballY - 40;
    }
};


//btn2 clicked = move up
for (i = ballY; ballY > height; i++); {
    if (btn2.checkClicked()) { 
           ballY = ballY - 40; //========= what to put here? =========
    }
};

};

setInterval(update, 10);
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks for your time.

-Jordan

Answer (score 0):

You should requestAnimationFrame for  paint continuosly your canvas and more than using ball position as a variable to increment / decrement you should use its speed, and the change position by speed * time passed like in the example.

Have fun with game coding.

```js
var canvas, ctx, mouseX, mouseY, btn1, btn2, ball, ballX, ballY, ballSize, Score, speedY = 0, end, start;

window.onload = function main() {

canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
canvas.width = width = 320;
canvas.height = height = 560;
mouseX = 0;
mouseY = 0;
btn1 = new Button(0, width, 0, height/2);
btn2 = new Button(0, width, height/2, height);
moveX = width/2;
moveY = height/2;
ballSize = 20;
ballX = moveX;
ballY = moveY;

document.body.appendChild(canvas);

init();
}


function init() {
document.addEventListener('click', mouseClicked, false);
start = new Date().getTime();
update();
}


function update() {
end = new Date().getTime();

ctx.clearRect(0, 0, 320, 560);

ctx.beginPath();
ctx.fillStyle="red";
ctx.rect(0, height/2, width, height/2);
ctx.fill();
ctx.closePath();
ballY += speedY * (end-start) / 1200
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.fillStyle = "black";
ctx.arc( ballX, ballY , ballSize/2, 0, Math.PI * 2, true);
ctx.fill();
ctx.closePath();
start = end;
requestAnimationFrame(update);
}



// button object
// checks if within bounds of 'button'
function Button(xL, xR, yT, yB) {
this.xLeft = xL;
this.xRight = xR;
this.yTop = yT;
this.yBottom = yB;
}

Button.prototype.checkClicked = function() {
if ( this.xLeft <= mouseX && mouseX <= this.xRight && this.yTop <= mouseY && mouseY <= this.yBottom) return true;
};



// event functions
// get position of mouse if its clicked on the canvas
function mouseClicked(e) {

mouseX = e.pageX - canvas.offsetLeft;
mouseY = e.pageY - canvas.offsetTop;
if (btn1.checkClicked()) { 
     speedY = 40;
}
if (btn2.checkClicked()) { 
           speedY = -40; //========= what to put here? =========
}
};
```